# Placing footer elements

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a school assignment where we can only use HTML + CSS (and PHP to include repeated elements, navbar + footer in this case).

For the footer I would like to place 3 elements in the 'Left' - 'Center' -  'Right' part of the footer.

Left: A newsletter bar to enter e-mail with a SIGN UP button

Center: 3 line text - Address, contact, opening hours.

Right: 2 icons - 1 for school and 1 for business'.

This is my code:

```
HTML: 
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
      <p class="left">Sign up botton here</p>
      <p class="right">School - business here</p>
      <p class="centered">3 lines with address, contact info, and opening hours.</p>
  </div>
```

```
CSS: 
.left{
  text-align:left;
  float:left;
}

.right{
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}

.centered{
  text-align:center;
}


.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background:#052D48;
}

.footer p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

How would I go about this? I've been reading and trying stuff for hours, but I just get more confused.

i.imgur.com/6IFJnxF.png Here is a picture of what I have in mind

Hope someone can help me in the right direction, thanks a lot!

Comment: what are you expecting? can you add an image may b

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6IFJnxF.png

Here is a picture of what I have in mind

Comment: Please put the image in your question for the usability.

Comment: I'd work with <div>'s and they contain the <p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flexbox and wrapping everything inside a container and a row with a 100% width. Then divide each block by X percentage. I changed the p tags with an unordered list.

```css
.row{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.left{
  width: 33%;
  height: 40px;
}

.right{
  width: 33%
}

.right ul{
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
}

.middle{
  width: 33%
}
.centered{text-align:center;}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-column{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.footer {
  
padding: 20px 10px;

   background:#052D48;
}

.footer p{
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left flex">
     <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="submit" class="" value="Submit">
      </div>
      

      
      <div class="right centered ">
        <ul class="flex-column">
          <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>     Address.</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact Info</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Opening Hours.</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="middle centered">
            <p class="">School - business here</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking the class off of `footer` and just use the `footer` tag to target the parent container. Then I would use `div` tags for each section instead of `p` tags, putting `p` tags inside the `div`. And my last recommendation, although your professor will think you're cheating, is to use flexbox. Enjoy. 
Also the `box-sizing: border-box;` is for the padding I added to the `footer` so it will still be `width: 100%;` instead of 100% + 40px

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {}

.centered {}

.centered p {}

.right {}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #052D48;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
  color: green;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="left">
    <p>Sign up botton here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="centered">
    <p>1 line</p>
    <p>2 line</p>
    <p>3 line</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>School - business here</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one idea.
https://jsfiddle.net/gztLhdk4/2/
you can customize it more based on your needs.

```
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
      <div class="left padd">
        <p>
        Sign up botton here
        </p>
        <p>
        <input type="text"> <button>sign up </button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="centered padd">
      <p>
      rttertertert<br>
      gereryrt ytyt<br>
      tryryrytru
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="right padd">
        <div>
          school
        </div>
        <div>
          business
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  </footer>

.left{
  text-align:left;
  float:left;
}

.right{
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}

.centered{
  text-align:center;width:50%;float:left;
}


.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background:#052D48;
}

.footer p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.padd{padding:5px;color:#fff;}
```